# Хорошая альтернатива GoogleMap для Android

Tags: android

В проекте используем GoogleMap (стандартный MapView от Гугл).
Много клиентов используют Huawei, а еще больше китайские плюшки и у них нет Google сервиса и соответственно не работает карта.

Предложите, пожалуйста, хорошую БЕСПЛАТНУЮ альтернативу googleMap.

Сам рассматриваю **OSMDroid** (раньше работал с этой либой, вроде хорошая альтернатива), но есть минусы, главный минус скорость работы (тайловый сервер медленно отдает слои).

Comment: у Huawei есть свой map sdk и много чего еще  https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-sdk-introduction-0000001050158633

Comment: ну точно делать для хуавей одну карту, а для других гугл не будем. Это получается писать х2 кода) Или хуавей сделало обертку? Сейчас загляну)) Спс)

Comment: Вот моя статья про Гугл и Huawei карты в одном приложении: https://habr.com/ru/post/521810/

Comment: Спасибо @ЮрийСПб. Навряд ли буду так делать в проекте т.к. кажется, что мега гемор, и если карты хуявея работают только на хуявее, то это не решает проблемы на других устройствах без гугл сервисов. Или карты хуявея можно юзать на любых устройствах? Если да, то зачем тогда не отказаться полностью от гугл?

Comment: @SKULL, использовать можно да, только на девайсах от Huawei. Если вам описанный  в статье способ не подходит - можете использовать специальный инструмент для автоматического конвертирования кода приложения для испоьзования гугл и/или Huawei сервисов (https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/huawei-toolkit/). Ну или да, совсем сторонние карты брать. Но вот чтобы они были и хорошие и бесплатные и везде работающие - такое вряд ли вы найдёте)

Comment: Ваш способ хорош, ну во всяком случае выглядит хорошим:) Просто хочется что то типа OSMDroid (наверное на нем и остановлюсь) чтобы не писать для каждого производителя свою карту (утрирую). Ну и да, хорошо != бесплатно.)